# repeat for loop multiple times with index value

Tags: php

```
$ron="1,2,3";
 $oc=12;
 $ronS=explode(',', $ron);
 foreach($ronS as $rone) {
 $res[]= $rone;
 }
```

i want to make output like the following

```
'1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3', '1', '2', '3','1', '2', '3'
```

Any idea friends..

Comment: Why is the question different now?

Comment: You completely changed your question. That makes effort of people who tried to help you to be pointless and makes answers to your question to look stupid.

Comment: Please do not change your question like this again. Normally I would revert your edit, but in this case you got it under the grace period, and it can't be reverted. But please don't do this again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arr = // somehow get your array
$max = 10; // number of printed values
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    $val = $arr[$i % count($arr)]; // get your value from array
    // do whatever you want with your value
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this one:

```
$val = $arr[$i % 4];
```

The number 4 is the array count.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four');

//$val = null;

$j=0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $val = $arr[$j];
    $j++;
    echo $val;
    if($j==3)$j=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple approach without use of cycle is to use `implode` function, like this:

```
$array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
echo implode (', ', $array);
```

More complex approach with use of `for` cycle and function:

```
$array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

function arrayToString(array $array){
    $length = count($array);
    $last = $length - 1;
    $str = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $str .= $array[$i];
        if ($i != $last){
            $str .= ', ';
        }
    }

    return $str;
}

echo arrayToString($array);
```

This approach can be simplified by adding usage of `substr` function:

```
function arrayToString(array $array){
    $length = count($array);
    $str = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $str .= "$array[$i], ";
    }

    return substr($str, 0, -2);
}
```

Another approach with use of `foreach` cycle and `substr` function:

```
$array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];

function arrayToString(array $array){
    $str = '';
    foreach ($array as $value){
        $str .= "$value, ";
    }

    return substr($str, 0, -2);
}

echo arrayToString($array);
```